# Error al leer formdata con Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, axios, formdata

Saludos como podria leer un formdata en el controlador?, estoy enviando por axios un formdata llamado "datos usuarios" y otro dato adicional llamado "estado", como podria leer el form data en el controlador ?

El form data tiene algunas variables entre ellas una llama "name", trato de leerla asi :  $request->datos_usuario->name pero me da error

:
ErrorException: Attempt to read property "name" on…:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

mira, para no complicarte, agrega tu variable estado a tu formData:

```
formData.append('estado': 'something')
```

Posteriormente, en tu data, envialo como:

```
data: formData
```

En tu backend, utiliza la función dd para que veas como te está llegando la información:

```
dd($request->all);
```